# ¿Cómo recorrer un array sus infinitos subarrays en JS?

Tags: javascript, array, json, bucles, iteradores

**CONTEXTO RÁPIDO**

Tengo una librería WYSIWYG o editor de texto, contiene la opción de crear un **lista** que genera **items**, también tiene la posibilidad de generar **subitems**, esto me devuelve un objeto de array con el contenido del items de la lista y  los posibles subitems de la siguiente manera:

```
{
 items: [
  {
    content: 'Lorem Ipsum1',
    items: []
  },
  {
    content: 'Lorem Ipsum2',
    items: [{...}, {...}] // subitems
  },
  {
    content: 'Lorem Ipsum3',
    items: [] 
  }
 ]
}
```

En HTML compilado se vería así:

```
 1. Lorem Ipsum1

 2. Lorem Ipsum2
   2.1. Lorem Ipsum2.1
   2.2. Lorem Ipsum2.2

 3. Lorem Ipsum3
```

**Mi pregunta es:**

*¿Cómo puedo recorrer todo esto teniendo en cuenta que pueden haber infinitos subitems?*

**Lo que ya tengo:**

```
convertedHtml += "<ol>";

items.forEach(function(li) {
  convertedHtml += `<li>${li.content}</li>`; // Items primarios de la lista
});

convertedHtml += "</ol>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto, viene a ser lo mismo que ya tienes pero de forma recursiva:

```
var convertedHtml = ''

function recursiva(items) {
  convertedHtml += "<ol>";

  items.forEach(function(li) {
    convertedHtml += `<li>${li.content}</li>`;
    if (li.items.length > 0) {
      recursiva(li.items);
    }
  });

  convertedHtml += "</ol>";
  return convertedHtml;
}

salida.innerHTML = recursiva(items.items)
```

Ejemplo:

```js
items = {
  items: [{
      content: 'Lorem Ipsum1',
      items: []
    },
    {
      content: 'Lorem Ipsum2',
      items: [{
          content: 'Lorem Ipsum3',
          items: []
        },
        {
          content: 'Lorem Ipsum4',
          items: [{
              content: 'Lorem Ipsum5',
              items: [{
                  content: 'Lorem Ipsum6',
                  items: []
                },
                {
                  content: 'Lorem Ipsum7',
                  items: [{
                      content: 'Lorem Ipsum8',
                      items: []
                    },
                    {
                      content: 'Lorem Ipsum9',
                      items: [{
                          content: 'Lorem Ipsum10',
                          items: []
                        },
                        {
                          content: 'Lorem Ipsum11',
                          items: []
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              content: 'Lorem Ipsum12',
              items: []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      content: 'Lorem Ipsum13',
      items: []
    }
  ]
}
var convertedHtml = ''

function recursiva(items) {
  convertedHtml += "<ol>";

  items.forEach(function(li) {
    convertedHtml += `<li>${li.content}</li>`;
    if (li.items.length > 0) {
      recursiva(li.items);
    }
  });

  convertedHtml += "</ol>";
  return convertedHtml;
}

salida.innerHTML = recursiva(items.items)
```

```html
<div id="salida">

</div>
```

Comment: ¡Tu respuesta fue bastante completa, de verdad muchas gracias por el nuevo concepto que aprendo hoy! "Recursividad". Había llegado a la solución con una de las sugerencias relacionadas que habían en la parte derecha pero estaba en PHP.

Answer (score 0):

espero esto te sirva:

```
      items.forEach(function(perm, index) {
         var contenido = perm.content
       }
```

con este foreach yo recorro arrays compuestos en un proyecto que tengo, ojalá sirva para adaptarlo a tu codigo.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero sólo realizaste un forEach. Lo que no he podido lograr es recorrer los posibles infinitos subitems porque dentro de un subitem pueden haber más subitems.